# Please help me identify the hymn being sung in this segment

Tags: shiva, gods, identification-request, stotra, hymn

https://youtu.be/ymoKnBGSFGM?feature=shared

From 18:27 to 22:46, there is a hymn being sung in what I'm told is the malkauns raga. I hear the phrases 'Niranjana Nirākāra', and 'Dukhha bandhana manoranjana jaya...'

I'm assuming it is about Lord Shiva because of temples in that segment of the video.

Can someone please tell me which hymn/stotram this is, and what it means? It would also be great if someone could tell me the singer's name.